# Comment code via menu or (foreign) keyboard shortcut in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/8511/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/C1/MC184F/MC184F?wid=572&hei=572&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400691344491)

In Chrome DevTools, many web pages show that the shortcut to toggle comment is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, but it does not work in my French keyboard.

Does anyone happen to know what is the real shortcut?

PS: I also need shortcuts to go through file tabs in `Sources`: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> don't work here...

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could try, but I could be way off.

In the Chrome Developer Tools, the following dictionary is used for mapping the key code associated with the key with a key name:

```
var keyNames = {
        3: "Enter",
        8: "Backspace",
        9: "Tab",
        13: "Enter",
        16: "Shift",
        17: "Ctrl",
        18: "Alt",
        19: "Pause",
        20: "CapsLock",
        27: "Esc",
        32: "Space",
        33: "PageUp",
        34: "PageDown",
        35: "End",
        36: "Home",
        37: "Left",
        38: "Up",
        39: "Right",
        40: "Down",
        44: "PrintScrn",
        45: "Insert",
        46: "Delete",
        59: ";",
        61: "=",
        91: "Mod",
        92: "Mod",
        93: "Mod",
        107: "=",
        109: "-",
        127: "Delete",
        173: "-",
        186: ";",
        187: "=",
        188: ",",
        189: "-",
        190: ".",
        191: "/",
        192: "`",
        219: "[",
        220: "\\",
        221: "]",
        222: "'",
        63232: "Up",
        63233: "Down",
        63234: "Left",
        63235: "Right",
        63272: "Delete",
        63273: "Home",
        63275: "End",
        63276: "PageUp",
        63277: "PageDown",
        63302: "Insert"
    };
```

It's possible your keyboard uses different key codes, so what you could do is put the following in the Console:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) { console.log(ev.which); }, true);
```

Press keys until you find out which key is associated with value 91 (Cmd for me) and 191 (/ for me), and then you know your shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for this method... I tried all the keys, my 91 is Cmd, whereas there is no key giving 191. Additionally, my 219 is `^` and 221 is `$`, however `cmd [` and `cmd ]` don't go through tabs in `Sources`. Also, sometimes 2 keys may share a same number. Eg, `)` and `-` are both 229. Is it possible to bind manually a key to a number (eg, bind `)` to 191)? Or do you suggest any shortcut binding software?